# How to return a substring from a text in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am fetching a value from Oracle DB which of type BLOB and in the form of XML. The XML is huge and I would like to search for strings which consits "Department" in it for example

```
 <ElectronicsDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>60</Capacity>
 </ElectronicsDepartment>
  <ComputersDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>65</Capacity>
  <ComputersDepartment>
  <MechanicalDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>65</Capacity>
  </MechanicalDepartment>
```

The XML is very long covering all the terms from I year to IV year of Engineering Degree. Now I would like to fetch details from the DB such the results should be in the format below

```
      Department     Term     Capactity  
      Electronics    I year      60
       Computers     I year      65
      Mechanical     I year      65
```

I have been trying the below query

```
  SELECT Department/(SELECT Department FROM University where Department like '%Department %' ), Term, Capacity From University
```

but the query is showing the error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB
```

Comment: You are trying to devide the Department value to another value. What do you want to make by using '/' sign ?

Comment: "/" is the syntax for the subquery in from clause

Comment: What is `university` - a view that has already extracted the XML data into a relational form? Or a table which has `department` as a CLOB containing XML, and separate term and capacity columns? Neither quite makes sense. Please add the table DDL to the question, and sample content of other columns.

Comment: University is a table and department is a coloum of type CLob in the form of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually starting from a CLOB that contains an XML document, of which you've shown a (invalid) fragment, then you can use the [built-in XML DB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb01int.htm) functions to extract the data directly from the XML.

You seem to want to match any node ending with `Department`, and to extract the first part of that node name as the department name, along with the term and capacity values under it.

You can do that with [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5094) and a suitable XPath, e.g.:

```
-- CTE to represent your raw XML CLOB, with dummy root node
with university (department) as (
select to_clob('<root>
  <ElectronicsDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>60</Capacity>
  </ElectronicsDepartment>
  <ComputersDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>65</Capacity>
  </ComputersDepartment>
  <MechanicalDepartment>
      <term>I year</term>
      <Capacity>65</Capacity>
  </MechanicalDepartment>
</root>') from dual
)
-- end of CTE, actual query below
select x.department, x.term, x.capacity
from university u
cross join xmltable (
  '//*[ends-with(name(), "Department")]'
  passing xmltype(u.department)
  columns department varchar2(20) path 'substring(name(), 1, string-length(name()) - 10)',
    term varchar2(10) path 'term',
    capacity number path 'Capacity'
) x;

DEPARTMENT           TERM         CAPACITY
-------------------- ---------- ----------
Electronics          I year             60
Computers            I year             65
Mechanical           I year             65
```

The `'//*[ends-with(name(), "Department")]'` only matches nodes that end with `Department`. The `'substring(name(), 1, string-length(name()) - 10)'` extracts all but the last 10 characters from that node name, getting `Computers` or whatever. The other two columns are more straightforward.

If you need to filter which CLOBs are included, you can add a `where` clause as normal after the `from` and the join to the XMLTable, e.g. to filter on a timestamp column in the `university` table:

```
select x.department, x.term, x.capacity
from university u
cross join xmltable (
  '//*[ends-with(name(), "Department")]'
  passing xmltype(u.department)
  columns department varchar2(20) path 'substring(name(), 1, string-length(name()) - 10)',
    term varchar2(10) path 'term',
    capacity number path 'Capacity'
) x
where your_timestamp_col >= timestamp '2017-06-01 00:00:00'
and your_timestamp_col < timestamp '2017-07-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: how do I give a where clause for the above select clause

Comment: @Sawyer - to do what? You can add a `where` clause  after the `XMLTable(...) x` as normal, but do you want to filter on particular department or term or capacity values after extracting, or limit which CLOB values you look at all for some reason?

Comment: There is a timestamp coloumn, so I would like to fetch the records betweem two timestamps

Comment: @Sawyer - then the same as any other `where` clause, after the `from` and `join` clauses. I've added an example, but this is nothing to do with the XML extraction really.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. but the sql is not working for the fields terms and capacity. It shows null values for the fields. and the where is also throwing error

Comment: Well, for the `where` clause you need to use your actual column name - you still haven't provided the table structure so I made up a name. The query works with the sample XML fragment you gave, maybe your real XML has slightly different node names or something. I can only work from the information you provide...

Answer (score 1):

I think your sql is wrong. 
This **/** is for **division** then it needs to be used with numbers. 
this subquery
*(SELECT Department FROM University where Department like '%Department %' )*
returns a string.

Then it is not working.

You can read some documentation about XML searching herE:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm

Comment: This document takes XML from a .xml file. The value i am fetching is a CLOB object and the value I want is is of type string

Comment: yep, but you can use [link](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14258_02/t_xml.htm) to fetch the data in more comfortable way then using sub-queries.

Comment: +1 for giving the links. I will definitely give the above as answer but I have do a reaserch on the doc by reading and finding a solution. Its  time consuming now but seems no other way.